# Mathematical notation to represent x% within x%

Tags: notation, percentages

What is the proper way to represent mathematically the expresion $x\%$ within $x\%$?

For example, $90\%$ of the bottles are $95\%$ full.

Comment: I'm not sure if your example really matches up with your intended question. Do you mean to ask how to mathematically represent a situation like "What percentage of the bottles are full, clear bottles, when 90% of the bottles are clear, and 95% of the clear bottles are full?" And even then, it is unclear what you mean by "mathematically represent."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to say. The correct way to represent that is just as you wrote: 90% of the bottles are 95% percent full. If you wanted to find the amount of whatever substance is contained in the bottles, and *that* is what you're trying to figure out how to represent, then let $b$ be the volume of one of the bottles, assuming that they are all the same, and $n$ be the number of bottles. The amount of substance is then $b*.95*.90*n+$however much there is in the other $\frac n {10}$ bottles.

Comment: I would argue that if you are not sure what the question is, you should comment instead of answering.

Comment: Note that this answer doesn't take into account how full the bottles that aren't 95% full are. For example, you get drastically different answers if the other bottles (those that are not 95% full) are all empty than if they are all completely full.

Comment: I answered instead of commenting because I do not have enough reputation to comment on other people's posts. Also, I do take into account the other bottles: look at the last full line of my answer. Obviously it is impossible to know the total amount of substance without knowing the amount in the other bottles, although I imagine that the idea is that they're empty.